# How to declare the nsurl variable with inital value as nil and also for nsarray?

Tags: objective-c

This is a simple and basics but I had a doubt that if it is declared globally with out initial value what happens ?

```
NSURL *finalURL; // here i need to initial value as nil if it is like this NSURL *finalURL=@""; giving warning.

nssarry *array=nil; // is this correct.
```

Please give the reply,
Thank You,
Madan Mohan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be static `NSURL *finalURL = nil;` and you have to define that inside a method. Then you can check if finalURL == nil and init it.

```
- (void)method
{
    static NSURL *url = nil;
    if(url == nil) {
        url = [[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://host"] retain];
    }
}
```

You can't do `NSURL *finalURL = @""` because `@""` is a String and not an NSURL!

`NSArray *array = nil;` is only correct if you capitalize NSArray correct!